# Problem with Zend Oauth and writing Access Token in mySQL database

Tags: database, zend-framework, twitter, oauth, token

I use Zend Oauth to connect my app to Twitter as described here:
http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.oauth.introduction.html

It works perfectly saving the Twitter Request Token and the Twitter
Access Token in the session using serialize and unserialize like this
(abbreviated):

```
1: $consumer = new Zend_Oauth_Consumer($config);
2: $token = $consumer->getRequestToken();
3: $_SESSION['TWITTER_REQUEST_TOKEN'] = serialize($token); //write Request Token
```

...and...

```
4: $consumer = new Zend_Oauth_Consumer($config);
5: $token = $consumer->getAccessToken($_GET,
unserialize($_SESSION['TWITTER_REQUEST_TOKEN']));
6: $_SESSION['TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN'] = serialize($token); //write Access Token
```

...and...

```
7: $token = unserialize($_SESSION['TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN']);
8: $client = $token->getHttpClient($configuration);
```

Now I want to save the Access Token in my mySQL database after line 6.
The problem is that as soon as I do this the entry in the db contains
weird characters like this:

```
O:23:"Zend_Oauth_Token_Access"?:{s:10:"�*�_params";a:4:{s:11:"oauth_token";s:50:"64658798-xOvsSyC83P2lhZRVvvaQLQddaifKO2qmN2KL91eaI";s:18:"oauth_token_secret";s:42:"R4nBLeWhNRXleKsN6H3crubYd2FEmfHFRtLbEh8gos";s:7:"user_id";s:8:"64658798";s:11:"screen_name";s:13:"MyTwitterAccount";}}
```

which leads to a notice (Error at offset 30 of 280 bytes)  in line 7
and and fatal error on line 8 because $token is a non-object.
So I tried to figure out the error and already posted the problem in
the Zend forum but nobody could help me...
My best guess is that it's an encoding error. The database and all my
documents are encoded corretly in utf-8 though and I never had
problems like this before...
A var_dump($token) in line 3 shows me that there are already crytpic
chars there. Here's an extract:

```
"Accept-Encoding" ["Content-encoding"]=>  string(4) "gzip" ["Content-length"]=>  string(3) "146" ["Connection"]=>  string(5) "close" } ["body":protected]=>  string(146) "�������E˹� ��п��J;80���4(,9��� ��.M��ؖ�"K���H���Q��a|;W����d2��.�׸Je�-���-y.���3��〺  object(Zend_Oauth_Http_Utility)#89 (0)
```

Is the content-encoding gzip the problem? Or is the problem caused by
Zend and the getRequestToken() method?
Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: i got the same problem. did you solve it in the end?

Answer (score 1):

Taken from the php.net help on serialize

wired caracters are added while serialisation for protected and private vars, it's a null byte

If serializing objects to be stored into a postgresql database, the 'null byte' injected for private and protected members throws a wrench into the system. Even pg_escape_bytea() on the value, and storing the value as a binary type fails under certain circumstances.

For a dirty work around:

$serialized_object = serialize($my_object);
$safe_object = str_replace("\0", "~~NULL_BYTE~~", $serialized_object);

?>

this allows you to store the object in a readable text format as well. When reading the data back:

$serialized_object = str_replace("~~NULL_BYTE~~", "\0", $safe_object);
$my_object = unserialize($serialized_object);

?>

The only gotcha's with this method is if your object member names or values may somehow contain the odd "~~NULL_BYTE~~" string. If that is the case, then str_replace() to a string that you are guaranteed not to have any where else in the string that serialize() returns.
Also remember to define the class before calling unserialize().

If you are storing session data into a postgresql database, then this workaround is an absolute must, because the $data passed to the session's write function is already serialized.